# How to programmatically call the DialogPage Cancel Button event

Tags: delphi-7, vcl, fastreport

Using Fast Report VCL component.

In the Report I would automatically cancel the report generation based on certain criteria.

I am using Fast Report DialogPage and put in 2 button (Btn OK and Btn Cancel)

The report is working correctly when the user presses the Ok Event (to Generate) and Btn Cancel (To cancel the report generation.)

What I would like to achieve is to call the Cancel Button Programmatically via from the Script to cancel the Report Generation.

How to do this?

```
IF <condition> then
    BtnCancel.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if <condition> then
  DialogPage1.ModalResult := mrCancel;
```

Comment: This works when I am putting this code in a button "onclick" event and when I am using the mouse to click on the button. However, it does not work if I put this in DialogPage1."OnShow" or  DialogPage1."Onactivate" event. The idea is to close the DialogPage1 with Dialogpage1 modal result = mrCancel;

Comment: `procedure frxReport1OnRunDialogs(var Result: Boolean);
begin
  if <condition> then
    begin                         
      Result := False;                                      
      Engine.StopReport;
    end;                
end;`

Comment: Thank You.  If <condition> then  Engine.StopReport;  did the trick.